# Finding Accuracy in SVM (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, classification, svm

I did SVM training and classification on sea images. I extracted features via HoG and trained features. After labeling features as 1 and 0, I tested my images. I always have 50% as a result. I thought maybe my images are bad so I tested every image individually and got rid of bad images. When I test one image, the accuracy is 100%. Then when I add another image into test images folder (which has 100% accuracy too), I got around 54% as a result. And in total I have two wrongly labelled featues in two test images. I did not understand why I am having a low accuracy. This is the formula I am using for the calculation;

```
acc = numel(find(Predict_label==test_label))/length(test_label);
disp(['Accuracy ', num2str(acc)])
```

Thank you.

Comment: provide a little more code. What are the dimensions of `Predict_label` and `test_label`. E.g. what is the result of `size(Predict_label)`? The part of the code you have shown looks correct. I also don't understand how you can get 54% if you have only 2 images.. It is either 0, 50 or 100..

Comment: There could be many reasons. It could be an issue with the HOG features - perhaps too small of a window, not enough precision on the angle bins, perhaps the normalization is incorrect etc. It could be your kernel you chose.  It could also be the images you chose. There's not enough here to tell you what's going on with your classification. You need to tell us more about how you are training your SVM. Please share some code or something that gives us insight on what you are actually doing to train your model. BTW, doing `numel + find` is very bad.  Just use `nnz`. Some images would be nice too.

Comment: I am extracting HoG features from valid points. I explained wrongly what I am training. I am training features around valid points. So I have 50 random location on the horizon line and 50 random location on the background. Every image has ground truth data. Dimensions are 198x1 for both. I have tried different kernels and as I said when I check images individually, accuracy is one hundred percent. The problems starts when I add second image. What is nnz? And which part should I add of my code(training,testing)?

Comment: Your explanation is really confusing.. Some images to explain what you are doing would help. Also, edit your question and add some more code. [`nnz`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) just replaces `numel(find(..`.

Comment: I have added some codes and these are the example result;
http://imgur.com/a/QbF7j
in the result image greens mean correct, reds are wrong.

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan I added the code and images.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, I have solved my problem. It was due to repetition of testing. I have just erased second testing in my code.